# How to quick record system audio in background on macOS?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, shell-script, applescript, audio-recording

On macOS Monterey I want to achieve what can be done on Windows with ShareX: **record system audio with a global hotkey and have the audio file automatically copied to the clipboard – all in the background.** If possible I would like to avoid using proprietary software to do this.

#### [x] Recording system audio

First issue is recording system audio on macOS. The app BackgroundMusic solved this easily. I tried getting BlackHole to work first, but I never figured out how to use system audio as input source while still hearing the audio playback. With BackgroundMusic this was never an issue though.

#### Method A: Using AppleScript and Voice Memos?

To record audio I first tried using AppleScript and Voice Memos, as [described in this guide](https://game2text.com/resources/macos/audio-to-clipboard/). Since written something has changed though, because Voice Memos  no longer runs in the background. I do not know why `set visible of process appName to false` and `perform action "AXRaise" of window 1 of process appName` stopped working. I contacted the author and he though OS updates might have broken the workflow at some point. If anyone knows how to fix it for Monterey that would be much appreciated. I have no clue how to debug it sadly.

```
set appName to "VoiceMemos"
if application appName is running then
    tell application id (id of application appName)
        quit
    end tell
    copy {do shell script "echo $HOME"} to {homeFolder}
    set recordingsFolder to homeFolder & "/Library/Application Support/com.apple.voicememos/Recordings"
    set audioFileName to (do shell script "cd " & quoted form of recordingsFolder & " && ls -ltr -A1 | grep m4a | tail -1")
    set the clipboard to POSIX file (recordingsFolder & "/" & audioFileName)
else
    tell application id (id of application appName) to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        set limit to 10
        set counter to 0
        repeat
            if exists window 1 of process appName then exit repeat
            if (counter > limit) then exit repeat
            set counter to counter + 1
            delay 1
        end repeat
        perform action "AXRaise" of window 1 of process appName
        keystroke "n" using command down
    end tell
end if
```

#### Method B: Using shell script and FFmpeg?

I tried a different method, namely a shell script with FFmpeg (and Automator). *I have yet to solve the copy output file to clipboard functionality by the way, but it seems doable as [discussed here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15318/how-to-use-terminal-to-copy-a-file-to-the-clipboard).*

This seems to work as intended:

```
#!/bin/bash


if ! pgrep -x "ffmpeg" | grep -q "avfoundation"; then
  pkill ffmpeg
fi

output_file="/Users/user/Desktop/a_$(date +'%y%m%d-%H%M%S').wav"
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":0" -t 600 "$output_file"
```

It starts and stops recordings all in the background. The only issue is the quality of the resulting audio files. I experience crackling/distortion/stuttering/speeding up issues on like half of the files while testing it out.

I tried changing these things without success:

- Setting sample rate to `-ar 44100`.
- Setting bitrate to `-b:a 128k`.
- Setting buffer size to `-max_delay 1000000`.
- Setting bit depth to 32 float with `-sample_fmt fltp` (32 float on my Mac when checking).

I have no idea what I am doing though, so go figure. Is there an obvious solution? I think that the problem is with FFmpeg settings, and not BackgroundMusic, seeing how there is no quality issues with different methods. With that being said, I do get this error when listing devices if it is at all relevant:

```
user@mac ~ % ffmpeg -hide_banner -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7ff144005cc0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7ff144005cc0] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7ff144005cc0] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7ff144005cc0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7ff144005cc0] [0] Background Music
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7ff144005cc0] [1] Bose QC35 II
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7ff144005cc0] [2] Built-in Microphone
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7ff144005cc0] [3] Background Music (UI Sounds)
[in#0 @ 0x7ff1440057c0] Error opening input: Input/output error
Error opening input file .
Error opening input files: Input/output error
```

#### Help

So, does anyone know how I can achieve this functionality on macOS? Is FFmpeg the way to go, or are there easier solutions out there? Can the Voice Memos script be fixed?

Comment: FWIW, I think most Mac users who need to record system audio just use Audio Hijack Pro from Rogue Amoeba rather than trying to cobble something together with built-in tools.